React Native & Expo-Contacts issues sorting records from device when values undefined with lastname not provided from device contact
I've got a screen that shows a FlatList of contacts from the device, no issues.  But, trying to sort the results by lastname and failing as some contacts don't have a lastname set within the device.
I extract the data:
const { data } = await Contacts.getContactsAsync({
  fields: [
    Contacts.Fields.emails,
    Contacts.Fields.firstName,
    Contacts.Fields.lastName,
    Contacts.Fields.company,
  ],
});

Then I'm trying to remove any undefined values, updating to ""
const availableCleanContacts =data.map((item) => ({
  ...item,
  firstName: item.firstName !== undefined ? item.firstName : "",
  lastName: item.lastName !== undefined ? item.lastName : "",
  company: item.company !== undefined ? item.company : "",
  emails: item.emails !== undefined ? item.emails : "",
}));

Then I've got a sort function:
  const sortByLastname = (a, b) => {
    const aLastName = a.lastName || "";
    const bLastName = b.lastName || "";
    // Compare the last names
    return aLastName.localeCompare(bLastName);
  };

And finally sort the results using the function
const finalData = cleanedCollateralData?.sort(sortByLastname)

It is working for me so far, but is this a good approach?  Any weird contact and the app crashes with the sort complaining.
All advice really appreciated.
